# Median Calculation in Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I need to calculate median value for the below input file. It is working fine for odd occurrences but not for even occurrences. Below is the input file and the script used. Could you please check what is wrong with this command and correct the same.

Input file:

```
col1,col2
AR,2.52
AR,3.57
AR,1.29
AR,6.66
AR,3.05
AR,5.52
```

Desired Output:

```
AR,3.31
```

Unix command:

```
cat test.txt | sort -t"," -k2n,2 | awk '{arr[NR]=$1} END { if (NR%2==1) print arr[(NR+1)/2]; else print (arr[NR/2]+arr[NR/2+1])/2}'
```

Comment: This should work `awk -F, 'NR>1{a[++x]=$2}END{asort(a);print (x%2)?a[(x/2)+0.5]:(a[x/2]+a[(x/2)+1])/2}'`

Comment: Use a scripting language. A floating-point number like "2.52e-3" is going to break your lexicographical sort.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that your input file has an additional line, containing the header. You need to take an additional step in your awk script to skip the first line.

Also, due to the fact you're using the default field separator, `$1` will contain the whole line, so your code `arr[NR/2]+arr[NR/2+1])/2` is never going to work. I would suggest that you changed it so that awk splits the input on a comma, then use the second field `$2`.

```
sort -t, -k2n,2 file | awk -F, 'NR>1{a[++i]=$2}END{if(i%2==1)print a[(i+1)/2];else print (a[i/2]+a[i/2+1])/2}'
```

I also removed your useless use of cat. Most tools, including sort and awk, are capable of reading in files directly, so you don't need to use cat with them.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
col1,col2
AR,2.52
AR,3.57
AR,1.29
AR,6.66
AR,3.05
AR,5.52
$ sort -t, -k2n,2 file | awk -F, 'NR>1{a[++i]=$2}END{if(i%2==1)print a[(i+1)/2];else print (a[i/2]+a[i/2+1])/2}'
3.31
```

It shouldn't be too difficult to modify the script slightly to change the output to whatever you want.